# Streaming Radio Stations on Ubuntu 16.04, and Firefox

Tags: streaming

When I go to a radio station's web site, and click on "Listen"  the icon changes from > to the pause || but these is no sound, and the counter ( 0.00) does not change.  I can go to Utube and get video and sound, and I've checked the earphone socket with the test option and it works.  Therefore, why doesn't the radio broadcast stream as it should?  Do I need to add some plugin, etc?
  Thank You.

Comment: Is this any radio station or a certain radio station only (which)?

Comment: I've gone to three different radio stations

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_radio_one - no issue here.

Comment: Thank you duncan.  I was trying to stream from Mpr.org, both the classical  station, and the news station;  also WMFE 90.7 public radio station.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I visited one of the site you commented on, mpr.org and was able to listen to streaming music from the classical section. (big mistake on my part, now I'm scarred for life) :)

I think you need to install adobe flash plugin. The installation process is simple:

1. open a terminal.
2. execute the following command: `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer`
3. the package itself is just a pointer to where it can download the plugin from the internet. Watch the terminal output and make sure the installation completed successfully.
4. if for some reason the installation failed, you can remove the package by executing: `sudo apt remove flashplugin-installer`, then do step 2 again.
5. upon successful installation, open firefox and type the following in the address bar: `about:plugins`
6. If flash plugin is installed and enabled in firefox, you should see the following:

> Shockwave Flash

```
File: libflashplayer.so
Path: /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
Version: 25.0.0.148
State: Enabled
Shockwave Flash 25.0 r0
```

7. visit the mpr.org site again and see if you can now listen to music.